# GStreamer pipeline crash (splitmuxsink)

Tags: gstreamer

This is my pipeline:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location='<my_rtsp>' 
    !  rtph264depay 
    !  h264parse  
    !  splitmuxsink location=/<my_path>/video%02d.mp4 max-size-time=60000000000
```

Every ~60 files (59-61) pipeline crash and i see this:

```
 **
    ERROR:gstsplitmuxsink.c:805:handle_gathered_gop: assertion failed: (queued_bytes >= splitmux->mux_start_bytes)
Aborted
```

is it possible to correct this error?

(I use GStreamer 1.8.0)

Comment: hm what has happened with the original question?

Comment: @otopolsky, in the hope for a speedy solution i create new question without C code.

Comment: well ok.. I do not remember if I reacted on the original question or not.. you could just make and update of the old one.. but yes sometimes you do not get any response ..